# Google Cloud aggregate billing per user or instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have many users and instances running  on google cloud and I was wondering if there was any view that could let me see the monthly bill associated to each instances or users?

Answer (score 1):

[Export billing data to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery) is a tool that you can monitor, analyze and optimize the cost. You can export your daily usage and cost estimates automatically throughout the day to a BigQuery dataset you specify. Exporting the billing data to BigQuery is a per project and this is not possible on a per user basis.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @milad's answer, if you're someone who's not comfortable with SQL, you can also export to a Cloud Storage bucket in CSV format and then run your analysis using Excel.